# using file upload ADF

Tags: file, oracle-adf

Mine is adf 11.1.1.6 application
My requirement is to provide user a dialog, though which user would select the file in his local machine and upload the same in some destination folder.

I have an inputfile and button.

```
   InputStream inputstream;    //global variable in the bean
    File file                              //global variable in the bean
```

on vcl of input file:

```
    file = (UploadedFile)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
    try {
        inputstream = file.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

on the click of button:

```
File destFile=new File("c:\\abc\\upload\\test.txt");
try {
    if(!destFile.exists()){
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("c:\\abc\\upload\\test.txt");
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buf)) > 0) { /// inputstream captured on vcl
                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I noted that the `test.txt` was created of size 0kb but without any content it.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What scope you are using for your bean? Why ain't you doing flush and close for your output stream?

Comment: Did you make your af:form attribute `usedUpload=true`

Comment: i did make the usesUpload="true"

Comment: My bean is in pageflowscope

Comment: Once i have the input stream, file can be generated as:  'code'
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
       
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\JDeveloper\\mywork\\uploadedFiles\\"+fileName));     //hard coded
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = inputstream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
                                                                   please refer [link](http://oracleadfamitt.blogspot.com/2014/07/FileUploadADF.html)

Comment: please refer:   http://oracleadfamitt.blogspot.com/2014/07/FileUploadADF.html